# "The more ... the more" construction

Tags: comparative-constructions

I would like to find out how to say some things about the guitar.
I came up with this sentence:

> The more the gauge ( of the strings)  the more sustain it provides.

I felt there is something wrong. So I thought of two other options:

> - The more the gauge is the more sustain it provides.
> - The larger the gauge the better sustain it provides.

Which one is the most grammatically correct option?

Answer (score 3):

"The more the gauge" does not sound natural to my (American) ear.

In (American) English, wire gauges are specified using numbers.  For small wires, larger numbers mean thinner wires.  Thus, it is confusing to say "the larger the gauge" -- do you mean "the larger the gauge number of the wire", or "the larger the wire diameter"?  "The bigger the gauge" has the same problem.

As Joe Dark suggests, "The heavier the gauge" is correct and natural.  "The thicker the gauge" is also correct, but is not as natural.