# The ... the ... structure: Is this sentence correct?

Tags: comparative

I would like to know if the following sentence is a correct usage of **the ... the ...** structure:

> The more the same products people can buy across the globe, the more
> similar countries are becoming. I think it is a negative trend because
> it might entail the loss of cultural diversity, which can be
> considered an adverse impact.

Actually, I'm thinking more about the first part. I don't know whether it is better to say the first or the latter:

1. The more **the same products** people can buy across the globe
2. The more people can buy **the same products** across the globe

Comment: Is it just the syntactic structure that you're asking about?

Comment: I'm just asking which one is correct!

Comment: Are you asking about the construction "[the more ... the more ...](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72460/the-more-the-more-construction)"? (In which case this was a duplicate.)

Answer (score 0):

The more the same products people can buy across the globe, the more similar countries are becoming. I think it is a negative trend because it might entail the loss of cultural diversity, which can be considered an adverse impact

Q. **I don't know whether it is better to say the first or the latter:**

The more the same products people can buy across the globe......
The more people can buy the same products across the globe

I would suggest neither.

**The global availability of products**

**availability**; noun; the fact that something can be bought, used, or reached,

---

**The more the same products people can buy across the globe, the more similar countries are becoming. I think it is a negative trend because it might entail the loss of cultural diversity, which can be considered an adverse impact**

*The global availability of products are increasingly seen as detrimental to the maintenance of national identity and cultural diversity*

Ref CED [availability](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/availability)